# Win2D only draw certain strokes of a geometry?

Tags: geometry, win2d

I am currently building a Win2D CanvasGeometry out of lines, arcs, and beziers using CanvasPathBuilder. I need to be able to only draw the stroke for some of them, the others need to participate in the placement of subsequent segments but not be drawn. Is there any way to do this in Win2D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just building multiple figures, since for each segment I had the end point, so if there was a segment that didn't need a stroke I could start a new figure. Seems to work ok.